# Remove older Hyperledger-sawtooth or pull latest repo and rerun build_all?

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I had previously brought down 0.8 and want to use new version.

Is it ok to update local repo and 'build_all' or must I remove all the older docker images first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be brute force, but this is what I ended up doing.

> Caution, the docker command will take out ***all*** images so if you want to
>   preserve some of them you may want a more selective approach.

### Sawtooth platform

1. Remove all docker images using this command `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`
2. Bring down the latest sawtooth compose file `sawtooth-default.yaml`
3. Execute compose `docker-compose -f sawtooth-default.yaml up`

### Sawtooth repo development

1. Clone the latest repository
2. Go to the root directory of the repo `cd ~\sawtooth-core`
3. At a minimum do `bin\build_all -l python`
4. I am using java so I do a `bin\build_all -l java` as well

Access to individual CLI and dev languages tested out 100% as per the Hyperledger Sawtooth documentation